# How can I create a shape in Illustrator which follows a path in descending order size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: This is how far I have come, but I don't know to reduce size in descending order of the brush.]I want to create something similar to the first image, but the angle of the star should be same.[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where it is failing.

Comment: i uploaded the image how far i have done it.
how can we add image in here comment box?

Comment: You can't add images in the comments, but you can upload images to imgur(dot)com or other image sharing sites, and copy and paste the link in your comment.

Comment: Also note that it's better to take screen shots rather than take photos of your screen.

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't have access to a pressure sensitive device....

This is *somewhat* possible via a blend. But due to how blends behave, in many cases spacing will require manual refinement.

- Create a blend, specified steps
- Replace Spine
- Alter blend options to set blend to be `Relative to path` and then increase steps to space the small end better
- Expand the blend
- *Manually* remove superfluous objects and then manually reposition a few objects for better spacing

[image]

*This is far from perfect*, but may offer a relative shortcut by supplying overall rotation and sizing to follow the path desired.

---

---

If you wish to achieve *precision*, then there's really nothing "automated" that will accomplish that which I am aware of. You would need to *manually* determine sizes, positions, and rotation degrees if you want things to be precise.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I've understood your question properly, it is kind of possible.

Here's one method which involves the use of a graphics tablet and pressure sensitive stylus, such as a Wacom.

Draw a star, and use it to create a Scatter Brush, with settings as shown below. When you use the Brush Tool, press harder at one end and release the pressure gradually as you draw. It might take a couple of attempts to get the pressure right.

[image]